# WD1000FYPS harddrive is marked 0 mb in 3ware (and no SMART)

Tags: hard-drive, raid, smart

After reboot my SATA 1TB WD1000FYPS (previously is was "Drive error") is marked 0 mb in 3ware web gui.

Complete message:

```
Available Drives (Controller ID 0)
Port 1  WDC WD1000FYPS-01ZKB0   0.00 MB NOT SUPPORTED   [Remove Drive]
```

SMART gives me only Device Model and ATA protocol version 1 (not 7-8 as it must be for SATA)

What does it mean?

Just before reboot, when is was marked only with "Device Error", smart was:

```
Device Model:     WDC WD1000FYPS-01ZKB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCASJ1130***
Firmware Version: 02.01B01
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Sun Mar  7 18:47:35 2010 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   188   186   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       7591
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       229
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   199   199   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       3
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000e   193   193   000    Old_age   Always       -       125
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   078   078   000    Old_age   Always       -       16615
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0012   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       77
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       1564
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   146   146   000    Old_age   Always       -       164824
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   117   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

What can be wrong with he? Can it be restored?

PS

new smart is

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD1000FYPS-01ZKB0
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   1
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Mon Mar  8 00:29:44 2010 MSK
SMART is only available in ATA Version 3 Revision 3 or greater.
We will try to proceed in spite of this.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
                  Checking for SMART support by trying SMART ENABLE command.
Command failed, ata.status=(0x00), ata.command=(0x51), ata.flags=(0x01)
Error SMART Enable failed: Input/output error
                  SMART ENABLE failed - this establishes that this device lacks SMART functionality.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

PPS There was a rapid grow of " 192 Power-Off_Retract_Count " before dying. The hard was used in raid, with several hards from the same fabric packaging box (close id's). The hard drives were placed identically. Rapid means  almost linear grow from 300 to 1700 in 6-7 hours. Maximal temperature was 41C. (thanks to munin's smart monitoring)

UPDATE

On the harddrive's PCB (on bottom) I have found contact pads with unusual colors. The most pads (not soldered) are Yellow, but some are blue and some are somewhere between orange and red. The max temperature for the drive was 42-43 Celsius. The 2 drives, which was next to the died one is normal, all unsoldered pads are yellow.

The harddrive was used for 2 years in RAID with rather big load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive has failed. RMA it back to WD.

Comment: Hello.
What is RMA?
I'm in russia. Seems, there are no official WD here..

Comment: @osgx: RMA = Return Materials Authorization. You should be able to find support in Russia for your WD hard drive here: http://support.wdc.com/index.asp?lang=ru Sorry I wasn't able to get a more precise link -- Мой русский разбит!

Comment: Your russian language is broken?? 
RMA in russia is available only to resselers, not to end users.

But I registered my hard on WD site. It is on warranty.
What can you say about last update (wrong colors on contact pads?)

Comment: @osgx: Not just broken, nonexistent. :) The colour change sounds like oxidation of the pads -- perhaps some contaminants (fingerprints, etc) were left on the pads, which have changed colour over time. If the board itself nor any of the ICs seem scorched, and the drive is not reporting overtemperature from its SMART log, there should be no issue with the warranty. If WD won't deal directly with you, then talk to the reseller you got the drive from.

Comment: разбит means "broken up, into pieces", like porcelain or glass cup after falling from table. :) Yes, it looks like oxidation, but it is blue on some pads (with normal pads near it), and red on some pads on different parts of PCB. I can't see IC, this is RE2 with ICs between PCB and hard drive itself.  Also, SMART is unreadable now. I posted last smart before the loss of drive. I can start smartctl on drive, but it show only "ATA protocol: 1" (not 8) and "SMART not supported".

Comment: I have PUIS enabled via config registers, not the jumper. Hard is used with 3ware 9650 raid controller. I can't plug drive into desktop, because intel sata controller will not send a "Start-up" command to the drive.

Comment: @osgx: Heh, that's Google Translate for you. Machine translations always suck. Perhaps I can word it better for the big G to handle more accurately... Не только я не могу говорить русский хорошо, я не могу говорить русский вообще.

Comment: What was the english prototype for "Мой русский разбит!" ?

Comment: Alex, do you know current status of Sun's project "Proximity Communication" (wireless near-field radio communication for chips)?

Comment: It was "My Russian is broken!" -- I was porting from German (which I don't know well) to Russian. In German, saying "mein Auto ist defekt" means "my car is broken" ("defekt" in German versus "defective" in English is not a coincidence), so I humorously use "mein Deutsch ist defekt" with Germans to let them know I don't speak German, and that usually gets a laugh out of them. Hence, "My Russian is broken". :)

Comment: I don't have any current inside info about Sun. I left a couple of years ago. While I had behind-the-firewall access back then, I don't anymore, so I'd only be able to troll Google.

Comment: Copper usually oxidizes green, but I've seen reddish oxidation on copper as well. I wouldn't really worry too much about it. The sudden growth of power-off retract count *is* interesting, though; if power is pulled from the drive suddenly (without telling the drive to power-off first), while the platters are still spinning the spindle becomes a generator and is creating a small amount of power which is used by the drive to retract the heads onto their ramp before the spindle slows too much (which would allow the heads to touch down, which would be bad). Perhaps flaky power or loose connector?

Comment: This drive sounds like it has "kicked the bucket", as we say in English. Monty Python fans would say it's "pining for the fjords". I don't think there's anything you can do that would fix it, especially since it's still responding but has lost its mind (re ATA spec, capacity, etc).

Comment: I sometimes troll wikipedia :)

I don't know German well too. 'Ich spreche keine Deutsche.'

What you did in the Sun?

Comment: My current project is linked with sparc and, partly, solaris.

Comment: I specified and deployed systems to clients, and fixed them when things went wrong. Salespeople asked us what the right technical solution was for the client so they could intelligently do up price quotes. It was a great gig, and I really enjoyed it while I was there. There's a lot of knowhow inside Sun, and their technical expertise is second to none. It's a shame to watch Oracle act like the Borg. http://www.sun.com/solaris -- I mean, Oracle Solaris? Come on. I died a little inside when I saw that.

Comment: @osgx: So, if my answer and subsequent comments were useful, feel free to mark it as accepted. :)